# Is the trace of the matrix exponential a manifold?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I am interested in the set of matrices $X \in R^{d \times d}$ for which
$$
\sum_i^{d} \exp(X \odot X)_{ii} = d
$$
holds. Here `exp` denotes the matrix exponential and $\odot$ is the hadamard product.
Is the set of $X$ for which above equation holds a manifold?

Motivation: The above equation indicates whether $X$ represents a directed acyclic graph, if interpreted as a weighted adjacency matrix.

Comment: It might help to note that the trace of the exponential is the exponential of the determinant, which is to say that your function can also be written as
$$
\sum_{i}^d \exp(X \odot X)_{ii} = \exp(\det(X \odot X))
$$

Comment: I can verify that $$\exp(\text{tr}(X)) = \text{det}(\exp(M))$$
but I am having problems verifying the above statement. Can you elaborate on it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.

As I note in my comment, we can write
$$
\sum_{i}^d \exp(X \odot X)_{ii} = \exp(\det(X \odot X)).
$$
Thus, the manifold of interest is the set of $X$ for which $\det(X \odot X) = \log(d)$. In order to show that this level set is a manifold, it suffices to verify that the gradient of $f(X) = \det(X \odot X)$ is non-zero at all points on the level set. To that end, we compute the differential as follows. Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\det([X + H ]\odot [X + H]) &= 
\det(X \odot X + 2X \odot H + o(H))
\\ & = \det(X \odot X) + 2\det(X \odot X)\operatorname{tr}([X \odot X]^{-1} [X \odot H ]) + o(H),
\end{align}
$$
which means that the differential of $f(X) = \det(X \odot X)$ is given by
$$
df(X)(H) = 2\det(X \odot X)\operatorname{tr}([X \odot X]^{-1} [X \odot H ]).
$$
We can see that this differential (and hence the gradient) is non-zero by noting that
$$
df(X)(X) = 2 \det(X \odot X) \operatorname{tr}([X \odot X]^{-1} \cdot [X \odot X])  = 2 \cdot \log(d) \cdot d \neq 0.
$$